# Connected negative contacts of 2 supplies

Tags: basic

When the negative contacts of 2 power supplies are connected with a wire they share the same base potential that can be associated as GND.

But why does this happen? For me it's a bit magical that the potential is suddenly the same although the two supplies are independent energy systems?

Apparently there's a current to equalize the potential.

Is that right?

I'm more interested in the physics, the behavior of the electrons.

Thanks

Comment: Or this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/690852/how-does-common-ground-work-in-this-arduino-project

Answer (score 3):

All conductors terminated at a common point are at the same potential.

Either the negative or the positive terminals of batteries or isolated power supplies may be connected to a common reference known as COM or GND.

Connecting the negative terminal of a power supply to COM or GND makes it a 'positive' power supply.

[image]

Likewise, connecting the positive terminal of a power supply to COM or GND makes it a 'negative' power supply.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, connecting any two independent metal objects together make them to be at same potential, regardless of what they are, e.g. terminals of two power supplies, terminals of two batteries, or two paper clips.

You can define that as any potential reference you want, in a battery powered equipment it is simplest to define the negative battery terminal that as 0V or "Ground" or whatever.

But if you use two 9V batteries in series to make a 18V battery, but you can also use that as supply with -9V, 0V, and +9V.

So in a car you might want to call the negative terminal of a 12V battery as 0V ground, while in a guitar pedal with two 9V batteries you might want to call the center tap betweem them as 0V ground.

Comment: Ok thank you, but in reality a wire has a tiny resistance. So what's the consequence? Are the two contacts still on the same potential? What is the physics behind the process of the harmonization of the potential?

Comment: @olympus_mons The resistance can be arbitary, it makes no difference. If no current flows in a resistance, there is 0V difference, even if resistance is gigaohms. As for physics, not sure about the terms, maybe electrostatics, if you have two charged particles and you make a galvanic connection between them, the charges move to balance and they are equipotential in respect to each other. Same thing when you shuffle on a carpet and touch metal handle on a fridge, you can feel the potential being equalized and then you are at same potential as the fridge metal chassis parts.

Comment: So to sum it up, there's a current between the contacts to equalize the potential. So for a short time interval until a common potential is established, there's a voltage drop.  So there's a common potential finally when the "amount of electrons" on both negative contacts is the same -> no voltage. Is that right? But that current would also cause the value of the voltages of both power supplies each as now there are on one side more electrons than before and on the other there are some electrons missing?

Comment: @olympus_mons Only if there was potential difference or charge imbalance to begin with. And there may be potential differences in the wire between due to inductance and also because nothing travels faster than speed of light in this universe. So you need to find a model that its practical, and usually connecting two metallic items isn't that difficult, they either are isolated or connected in an ideal world.